# Even numbers greater than 10 as sum of two specific odd numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

It is well known fact that it is very hard to prove [Goldbach's strong conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) but perhaps some weaker variations can be proved(or disproved) ,so my question is:
Is it true that every even number greater than 10 can be represented as the sum of an odd prime number and an odd [semiprime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime)?

Comment: Have you seen Chen's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen%27s_theorem) ? I don't know if that can be extended to just the prime + semiprime case, though

Comment: @yatima2975: That's probably as good an answer as this question will get here. (I was going to post it myself before I rechecked the comments.)

Comment: @yatima2975,Chen's theorem states for every sufficiently large even number while my question is more specific since it states for each even number greater than 10.....

Comment: pedja: It's apparent in yatima's comment that he knows that.

Comment: I wrote a small c++ program that verified the conjecture for all even numbers less than 600k and larger than 10. So perhaps it's true.

Comment: http://www.math.utoledo.edu/~jevard/Page015.htm Has some references regarding improvements on Chen's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Some counterexamples: 12, 14, 16, 30.  [My perl program](http://pastebin.com/2wF8nB2A) can't find any more smaller than 100000.

EDIT: I didn't know that semiprimes are defined to include squares.  When I comment out the line that filters them, nothing is output up to 100000.  I'll leave this answer here as an example of wrongness.

Comment: 9+3=12, 9+5=14, 9+7=16, 25+5=30. Are you forgetting that $p^2$ is semiprime in your code?

Comment: @Dan,12=3+9,9 is odd semiprime ;14=5+9 ;16=7+9; 30=5+25 ,25 is odd semiprime...so you are not right this time